How to add bot to channel using WTelegramClient?
I use Client.Channels_InviteToChannel but it asks for access_hash.
How do I suppose to get access_hash if I never interacted with bot before ?
Note that I'm admin of channel. Also have bot's token.
I can do that manually using telegram app.
Dim BotFullUser = Await Client.Users_GetFullUser(New InputUser(BotId, 0)) 
'FAILS HERE
'TL.RpcException: 400 USER_ID_INVALID

Dim BotUser = New InputUser(BotId, BotFullUser.users.ElementAt(0).Value.access_hash)
Dim Ch = "{channel_id}:{channel_hash}".Split(":")
Await Client.Channels_InviteToChannel(New InputChannel(Long.Parse(Ch(0)), Long.Parse(Ch(1))), BotUser)

Edit: Second attempt:
Dim BotUser = (Await Client.Contacts_ResolveUsername(BotUserName)).User

Dim Ch = "{channel_id}:{channel_hash}".Split(":")
Await Client.Channels_InviteToChannel(New InputChannel(Long.Parse(Ch(0)), Long.Parse(Ch(1))), BotUser)
'FAILS HERE
'TL.RpcException: 400 USER_BOT


This works now. Actually we can't add bot without making admin.
So just Channels_EditAdmin is enough to invite bot.
Dim BotUsername = ...
Dim channelId = ...
Dim Channel_Access_Hash = ...

Dim Bot = Client.Contacts_ResolveUsername(BotUsername)
Dim InputChanell = New InputChannel(channelId, Channel_Access_Hash)
Dim C = Await Client.Channels_GetFullChannel(InputChanell)
Dim PreviewChannel = C.chats.First.Value
Dim channel = CType(PreviewChannel, Channel)
Await Client.Channels_EditAdmin(InputChanell, user, channel.admin_rights, "Administrator")

Thanks @Wizou for help

use Contacts_ResolveUsername to get user structure for your bot

Hi I tried. But it raises RpcException: 400 USER_BOT. I edited my post. Please review code.
